# Xamarin - Add PCL project to SAP?

Tags: c#, xamarin

In the free book "Creating Mobille Apps with Xamarin.Forms" It states:

> If you’ve created a Xamarin.Forms solution with a Shared Asset
>   Project, you can add a new PCL project to the solution by selecting
>   the Class Library (Xamarin.Forms Portable) template.

How would I go about doing this? I've added reference to each of the platform projects.

Answer (score 0):

It is said that you can refer a PCL project when you use a SAP. But, very honestly I dont see the use of adding both SAP and PCL. Its normally either one of them. But If you need to add a a PCL project to the exisitng project, you should refer them in the native project.

Comment: I just wanted to test. I am a total beginner with xamarin. Also, I couldnt get PCL to work, it kept coming up with  metadata error. I did try look up solutions but nothing worked

Comment: What error does it throw? and are you using visual studio or xamarin studio?

Comment: Hello, I am using VS 2015 Professional, and something about metadata, a dll could not be created.

Comment: Hello, Its fine, im getting along happily with Shared Project :D thanks though :)